# Move value from local stack to heap? (C++)

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

How can I take an object-as-value result from a method call and place it on the heap?

For instance:

The Qt [`QImage::scaledToWidth` method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#scaledToWidth) returns a copy of the `QImage` object.

Right now I'm doing:

```
QImage *new_img_on_heap = new QImage(old_imgage_on_heap->scaledToWidth(2000));
```

Is this the only way?  Seems like it's going through the trouble of making a 3rd whole new object when I already have a perfect good one on the stack.

The reason I want to put it on the heap is because the real `QImage` is large, and I want it to outlive the lifetime of the current method.  I was intending to stuff a pointer to it in a field of my class.

I know that `QImage` has some sort of implicit data sharing, but I'm not exactly clear on how it works under the hood. Plus, I wanted to know a general solution should I ever need to use objects not as well designed as Qt's.

Comment: I think the copy to a new heap-allocated object is the right way (anyway a heap memory allocation needs to be made). I'm just wondering how C++ move would handle this behind the curtains.

Comment: @Clodéric: If the type is movable, then it will call the move constructor rather than the copy constructor (the argument being a temporary). I would assume that the `QImage` object would be *movable* in a C++0x compatible version of the library (the image buffer is probably held in dynamic memory most probably)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I know that, I was just wondering how it worked under-the-hood to move an object between the heap and the stack (If it's possible without doing a copy - which I doubt).

Comment: @Clodéric: It does not *move* the object, but rather the resources managed by the object. Imagine that the QImage contains a pointer to a byte array, then the move constructor could swap the pointers in the source and destination objects. There will still be 2 objects, but the contents of the source will be *moved* to the second object. The [same approach](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/09/rule-of-3-4-swap.html) can be manually handled (in some cases) in the C++03 by creating an empty object and using a hand tailored `swap` function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An object is identified by its address.  If you want it at another
address, you have to construct a new one; you can't move objects.  (Even
with C++11, the new “move” semantics don't actually move an
object; they provide an optimized way of moving its value, if you know
that you won't need the value from where you're moving it.)

Comment: +1: It is *very important* to notice the difference from the object and the value, and the fact that *move-constructor* and *move-assignment* do not *move* the object, only the contents can be moved (and not always)

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you should prefer the stack to the heap in most cases.

Secondly, when you allocate objects on the heap you should wrap the raw pointer in some managed object which is on the stack. If for nothing else, do it for exception safety.

Thirdly, Qt objects usually [do exactly that](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) i.e. there's no advantage in writing `new QImage` or `new QMap<int>` etc.

Nevertheless the right way to move a non-heap object onto the heap is to say

```
new ObjectType (old_instance)
```

If you do this with a temporary object, such as

```
new ObjectType (create_object ())
```

then it will probably [elide the extra copy](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) (link broken for me -- [cached](https://web.archive.org/web/20130604044046/http://cpp-next.com:80/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/))

Comment: The decision of stack and heap (or more precisely automatic vs. dynamic storage) should be more related to object lifetime than to the sizes of the objects. If the QImage is to outlive the current context then you cannot have automatic storage duration in the current scope.

Comment: As of *copy-elision*, it will not take place in that particular situation. In particular if the destination object is not an object with automatic storage duration chances are that the copy cannot be elided. You can read on what goes under the curtains with copy elision [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html) and [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html). The compiler can only elide the copies if it can use the same memory for the object and the temporary, the location of which is determined by the calling convention.

Comment: I agree completely about object lifetimes being more important, but a sufficiently large object *must* go on the heap or it will break the stack. I also agree that elision depends on the calling convention. However, there's nothing in my or the OP's example that will suppress it.

Comment: *Sufficiently large* is something that is actually hard to identify for non-experienced programmers. Is a `std::vector<int>` containing 10 elements *sufficiently large*? what about 100.000.000 elements? Or does the number of elements in the vector not matter at all? What about a QImage from a 18M pixel camera, is that *sufficiently large* to have to use dynamic memory? Does the size of the stored image actually matter at all?

Comment: The second half of this answer is great.  The first half (prefer the stack) is too simplistic.  A choice of the stack or the heap should be first one of lifetime.  If lifetime is short, but the object very large, then the heap might be necessary, but size consideration should be secondary to lifetime.

Comment: Okay I've stripped the answer down a bit. Better now?

Comment: @David Both your links are the same.  Did you have a 2nd source?

Comment: David, elision has *nothing* to do with static vs dynamic storage. Given that `MyObject*p` exists and points to uninitialised memory, it can be pushed into a function as a target for the return value and it matters not the slightest whether `p` points to stack or heap memory.

Comment: I'll tell you what, write a test class which prints during copy operations. See if `TestClass x(create())` prints any differently to `new TestClass(create())`. It sure doesn't for me.

Comment: @spraff: I have gone back to basics and read the calling conventions, which is something I should have done a while ago. The calling convention for return by value in both 32 and 64 bit, Microsoft and GCC does not use a fixed location for the object (as I wrongly thought), but rather passes a pointer to the location of the object to be returned (unless it fits in the registers), and that means that the objects can be located anywhere. I had the false believe that the returned object (for large objects) had to be layed out in the stack. +1

Answer (score 0):

Since the method

QImage QImage::scaledToWidth ( int width, Qt::TransformationMode mode = Qt::FastTransformation ) const

does not return a QImage address (i.e. QImage& ....) than I think you are out of luck. You are stuck with a copy. Unless you want to recompile the QT libraries to change that function signature so that it does not return a copy.

What is so bad about having that object on the stack anyways?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following trick. Idea is to put your value to some structure and construct structure in heap. In this case copy elision works. No copies or moves are performed. Unfortunately it does not work on VS2017. But it works in G++ 8+ and probably in VS2019.

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct C{

    C() = default;
    C( C&& ) = delete;
    C( C const& ) = delete;

    C& operator=( C&& ) = delete;
    C& operator=( C const& ) = delete;
};

C foo() {
    return C {};
}

struct X {
    C c;

    X() 
        : c (foo()) // here is how trick works
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    auto x = std::make_unique<X>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The premise of this question/ask is incorrect in that it assumes that the image data for QImage has the same lifetime of the QImage object itself.

> The reason I want to put it on the heap is because the real QImage is large, and I want it to outlive the lifetime of the current method. I was intending to stuff a pointer to it in a field of my class.

This statement is *not correct* as it would be a VERY BAD thing for something like QImage, and very quickly fail by popping "stack" limits. It would also make assignments very slow!

Rather, QImage, like many C++ objects that deal with large and/or external data, is effectively a *wrapper* around internally managed memory of a different lifetime. This can be seen in [the QImage source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/image/qimage.cpp.html#155); QImage contains QImageData, and QImageData malloc's the internal buffer independently of the original QImage's lifetime.

As the bulk of the data is "outside" of QImage, there is little reason to prefer `new QImage` instead of using `QImage` and auto lifetimes for sake of the (incorrectly perceived) storage duration of the image data; QImage implements copy and move sanely*, so that all underlying image data (and underlying allocation of such) is shared.

*In [QImage's copy ctor](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/image/qimage.cpp.html#_ZN6QImageC1ERKS_) the 'ref count' of the QImageData is briefly extended until the destruction of the previous object, while in the move the QImageData's lifetime could be directly transferred (in comment, missing from that source?). Regardless, neither case actually makes a copy of the underlying image data which would be expensive.

So, to answer the question: `new X(non_ptr_X)`, and let the properly written constructors/design do their thing, which is an implementation detail; and hopefully one of agreeable performance characteristics. YMMV.