# Allocate stack object (returned by value from function) to heap efficiently?

Tags: c++

I have an object `Foo` returned by value from function `makeFoo()` and I need to pass ownership of it to another object `FooHolder(Foo* foo)` through a pointer.

My current solution is create a `Foo` heap object by passing the on-stack `Foo` object to a `Foo` constructor with move semantics:

```
Foo foo = makeFoo(...);
Foo* fooPtr = new Foo(std::move(foo));
fooHolder.set_value(fooPtr);
```

, but I'm hoping there is a more efficient solution that avoids stack allocation and copying.

Note I can't create a `makeFoo` function that returns a pointer, since the call is an external API.

Comment: If you want your fooHolder to have ownership, you should probably be using unique_ptr

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response! The ```FooHolder`` object is also part of an API that I can't edit, although what you said makes sense!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move value from local stack to heap? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571294/move-value-from-local-stack-to-heap-c)

Comment: You can't pass *ownership* of the object anywhere; even after `std::move(foo)`, the object `foo` still "belongs" here, although it may have been "emptied" by the receiving object. You can't avoid making at least one "move-copy".

Answer (score 0):

Write the code as

```
Foo* fooPtr = new Foo(makeFoo(...));
fooHolder.set_value(fooPtr);
```

Beginning with C++17 the return value of `makeFoo` is constructed in the heap location directly, which avoids the temporary object entirely.